# How do I let other people view my photos I’ve uploaded to Photobucket?

Tags: photobucket

I've created an album and uploaded a load of photos to Photobucket, but when I send the link to my friends all they see is a login screen.

I've searched but I can't find the option to make the album publicly visible.

I don't want to make all the images public, just the ones in one particular album.

It would be great if I could limit the viewers to a few people - is this at all possible?

Comment: The embarrassing thing is I have actually forgotten how to do this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your main account status to public, and then set individual albums to private.  Here are more details from the [Photobucket help](http://pic.pbsrc.com/help/PhotobucketHelp.htm):

> You can edit your album privacy settings on the All Albums page. Your main account status must be set to Public before you can change the privacy setting of individual albums. See Change your account privacy settings for instructions. If your account is public, you can change the status of individual albums, at the first level, within your account.
>
> Log into your Photobucket account.
>   Click All Albums in the secondary
>   menu. A list of all your albums
>   displays. Mouse over the album whose
>   privacy you want to edit. Click the
>   edit link. The Edit Album pop-up
>   displays. Check it out Choose whether
>   the album is public or private. Notes:
>
> Only albums at the first level can be
>   set to public or private. Albums at
>   the second, third, etc. level inherit
>   the privacy setting of the first-level
>   album within which they exist. If you
>   make an album private, you can add a
>   guest password. To test guest access,
>   you must log out of your Photobucket
>   account. Make sure any guest passwords
>   you assign are different than your
>   main administrative password. If you
>   make them the same or similar, your
>   chances of logging into your account
>   as a guest or someone guessing your
>   master password are more likely. When
>   you assign this password, use a
>   combination of letters and numbers for
>   added security. Passwords are case
>   sensitive, so a combination of upper-
>   and lower-case letters is also good.
>   Click Save. If you do not click Save,
>   your changes are discarded.